# Windows Phone 7 - C# How to use ListPickerItem in code without it crashing?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, crash, listpicker

Listpickeritem thus far seems to be a bit of a head ache insofar that it crashes very easily.

I have the following code which crashes when the listpickeritem is selected while running the app:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
         ListPickerItem item = new ListPickerItem();
         item.Content = i.ToString() + "%";
         item.FontSize = 35;
         listPicker1.Items.Add(item); 
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker Name="listPicker1" Margin="251,117,92,-93" Width="113" FontSize="40">
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Does anyone know of a way to set the fontsize throuch c# without it crashing? If I manually enter the xaml, that also causes crashes and I don't want to have to type a long list when I can do it programmatically instead.

*Edit* Answer below.

Error message that was originally coming up: Unhandled exception ">PivotApp1.dll!PivotApp1.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 125 + 0x5 bytes  C#"

Comment: What do you mean by 'crash'? What exactly happens when it gets to this point in your code?

Comment: There is an unhandled exception as soon as the listpicker is selected. ">PivotApp1.dll!PivotApp1.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 125 + 0x5 bytes C#"

Comment: What does the message property of the exception say?

Comment: I've resolved the problem, thanks for your attempted assistance. I appreciate it. Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I was trying to do was create a listpicker list for percentage between 1 and 100 for a user to select. It seems like a lot of code for a simple task, but unfortunately there wasn't any other way to modify the listpicker fontsize. The following code was the solution I came up with to solve my problem:

XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPicker1" 
                    Margin="251,117,92,-93" 
                    Width="113" >
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percent}" FontSize="40" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percent}" FontSize="40" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Created a new class called Percentage.cs

```
public class Percentage
{
    public int Percent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Then from within my class that I wanted to control the listpicker from, I added the following code to create a list of 1 to 100 using a list created from the Percentage class:

```
   List<Percentage> percentage = new List<Percentage>();
   for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
   {
        percentage.Add(new Percentage() { Percent = i });

   }
   this.listPicker1.ItemsSource = percentage;
```